# Using FRP (and immutable collections) with many objects, shown on a grid

Tags: c#, wpf, reactive-programming, frp

I've been reading about FRP lately and really liked the idea so far. There are a couple of things I haven't found much information about, and one of them is this: If I use, for example, a WPF grid for displaying my data (with some thousands of rows), how should I wire the updates to the grid?

I should note that I have relatively little experience with WPF too, but as far as I understand, this would usually be solved by binding the grid to an `ObservableCollection<T>`, which, if I understand correctly, is very good at handling the updates (meaning updating, adding or removing single items is handled with good performance).

So then, if I wanted to use FRP with immutable collections, this isn't applicable. But what other options are there? If I re-fill the whole grid with each and every update, add or delete, I would guess the performance is quite appalling.

I also don't really have example code to show because, frankly, this is such a basic thing that I wouldn't know where to start without knowing how to do this first. And while I'm specifically talking about C# and WPF in here, I'm also interested in the general principles.

Comment: If you have only immutable collections and want to emulate collection mutability in WPF UI, then you only have an option of changing ItemsSource with every update. This situation has only downsides, IMO, as you'll have to cover the functionality that is done automatically for `ObservableCollection` - selected item persistence, scroll position, etc.

Comment: Hmm ok, so I guess that means I really should choose one or the other - Immutable collections or easy binding to UI.